# Threading start back again after pausing

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I am using threading in my code , thread are created using function:

```
private void InitializeBackgoundWorkers()
{

    for (int f = 0; f < maxThreads; f++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "Starting Thread : " + (f + 1));
        threadArray[f] = new BackgroundWorker();
        threadArray[f].DoWork +=
            new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorkerFiles_DoWork);
        threadArray[f].RunWorkerCompleted +=
            new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorkerFiles_RunWorkerCompleted);
        threadArray[f].ProgressChanged +=
            new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorkerFiles_ProgressChanged);
        threadArray[f].WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        threadArray[f].WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

    }
}
```

And the doevent is something like :

```
private void backgroundWorkerFiles_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    int flag = 0;

    while (rowCounter < allPostingRows.Tables[0].Rows.Count && flag == 0)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)
        {

            if (threadArray[i].CancellationPending == true)
            {
                flag = 1;
                threadArray[i].CancelAsync();
                worker.ReportProgress(0, "Thread Paused:");
            }

        }

        if (flag == 0)
        {
             //perform work here
            }
    }
}
```

And on button i try to cancel the threads using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)
{
    threadArray[i].CancelAsync();
}
```

Am i cancelling the thread correctly? As when they get canceled i see the line in listbox saying thread cancelled so it does go to the cancellation code but after some time it restarts

Thank you

Comment: How are the workers started? Do all workers restart? Do they restart from the beginning?

Comment: @PeterRitchie  i reduced all the extra code and made it nice and simple any help now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you really understand `BackgroundWorker`.  The `DoWork` event handler is supposed to be a handler for one unit of work.  `DoWork` is called with one thread.  It doesn't make sense to call `CancelAsync` from within a `DoWork` handler--that's independent of any and all other `BackgroundWorker`'s.   Within the `DoWork` handler it should only be checking one `CancellationPending`, the sender's (once cast to `BackgroundWorker`, in your case `worker`).

But, otherwise, calling `CancelAsync` from the UI is the correct way to cancel a particular `BackgroundWorker`.

Background workers are not "thread"s.  You''re not cancelling a thread, you're cancelling the worker--which allows the DoWork handler a chance to exit before it is done it's work.